# Understanding bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can you help me understand what bootstrap is? I know people is it for styling pages but can you clarify it to me? A big company like Twitter, Facebook or YouTube can use it?

Comment: Twitter certainly use(d?) it since they made it. I think wikipedia makes a good presentation of that front-end framework, check it out : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)

Comment: It's certainly got nothing to do with Python or Flask, so not sure why those were your tags of choice

Comment: Other CSS + JS frameworks exist such SemanticUI or MaterialUI, but Bootstrap was/is really the most widely used one

Comment: Sorry for the tags, but I'm studying Flask and I thought it was only for it. Really sorry

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a very nice set of "styles" for all elements of any webpage. With it, a developer can focus on *what* they want to build (i.e. the elements) and very easily apply all the styling (including a lot of the colours, positioning, layout, movement/javascript) by simply adding few lines of code at the start of the webpage and adding a bootstrap class to an element, or wrapping parts of their webpage in a `<div>`.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) is an excellent example of a very basic site that is made to look professional very quickly using very simple bootstrap. Click on "full page demo", then view -> view source to see the source code.

You can see some classic bootstrap classes like

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
```

and

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MiguelFerreira no problem! I recommend you go to the link I provided, copy the source code into a text document and name it mypage.html, then open it in a browser. Then play around with some of the code and refresh the page to see the effect. Change the alignment, colours, fonts, etc etc. Youl will pick it up quickly

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a free and open-source front-end framework developed with css and javascript.

For styling and other change of the html, we make CSS classes and ids. And the main work we do in the css file and js file . But in bootstrap there is already some files which have many built in classes and ids .

After adding bootstrap to a html file we can do many work by only calling those classes and ids .

like , 
`<p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>`

only calling the class   "text-center" we can align text  center . No need to do any other css .

Many big company like Twitter, Facebook or YouTube can use it. On the other hand some make their custom files like bootstrap.